# Getting currently playing song name in AVRCP or Establishing browsing channel in AVRCP

Tags: android, l2cap, avrcp

I am trying to create a AVRCP app on Andriod, from which I will be connecting to another device (smart phone). Currently I am able to play, pause songs of other device from my app, but I want to get the song name of the currently playing song.
Is this possible on Android?

I have connected to other device over L2CAP and I am able to play and pause songs on other smartphone.

I have gone through the AVRCP profile documentation and the documentation mentions about establishing a browsing channel before getting any notification from connected device.
But how to establish a browsing channel?

If someone has tried this before, please let me know

Comment: any new experiences about AVRCP/A2DP u can share with community?
is your project open source? did u work more on it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the song name, no need to establish browsing channel. if it support the avrcp 1.3 version then you will get song name, artist name, track number etc...

regards,
V.mallikarjuna rao